# Django permission's specific to templateview

Tags: django, django-views, permissions

How to create multiple permission classes that would restrict user from accessing a template view ( that doesnt use any model).
For example: I have 4 user categories - ( admin, management, principal, teacher). I have a Admin dashboard template view which should be restricted to user type=Admin.

I would like to be able to write multiple permission classes, which I can then use in combination in any view.

Following code generates 403 error:

```
class AdministratorPermission(AccessMixin):
    def has_permission(self):
        return True


class GeneralPerm1(AccessMixin):
    def has_permission(self):
        return True


class DashboardView(PermissionRequiredMixin,
                    LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'administrator/dashboard.html'
    permission_required = (AdministratorPermission,GeneralPerm1)
```

Is there a way to do something like [DRF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38873561/3842788) permissions.

Thanks

Comment: What makes you assume this should show a page? The classes you handed to `permission_required` are not permissions. It looks like you think because `has_permission()` returns True for these classes, anyone should be able to view the page.

Answer (score 1):

**Permission1Mixin.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import AccessMixin
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class IsAdministratorMixin(AccessMixin):
    """ if user is not administrator, decline permission """

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        if user is authenticated and administrator
            we are good. otherwise permission denied
        """
        if request.user.is_authenticated and \
                request.user.category.category == \
                UserCategoryEnum.ADMINISTRATOR.value:
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

        raise PermissionDenied('Permission denied')  # decline permission
```

**view.py**

```
class DashboardView(IsAdministratorMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'administrator/dashboard.html'
```

This way we can create multiple independent permission mixins and use them in combination.

Comment: They're not permission mixins, but AccessMixin as you can see from the class they inherit. [Permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) are tied to Models on side and Users or Groups on the other. Access Mixins are used for this case, where access it not tied to Model based permissions. You would normally do this with [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin).